# How to tell VS10 One-click deployment to copy certain files and folders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, web-config, one-click-web-publishing

I'm trying to use the Web One Click Publish feature in VS10 to push my asp.net app to IIS.  I have some .resx files and another folder for uploaded images, none of these got copied to IIS.  How do I tell it to copy the specified files and folders

Thank you so much,
Ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure that the properties of the .resx files have "Copy to Output Directory" set to *Copy Always*?

[image]

---

UPDATE: I apologize for not reading your question closely enough.

According to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434211.aspx, you should check the *Items to Deploy* drop down list and make sure you have one of the following two options set:

**All files in this project.** All files included in the project are deployed to the destination server. Files that are in the project folder but are not included in the project are excluded.

or

**All files in this project folder.** All files in the project folder are deployed to the destination server, even if they are excluded from the project.

[image]

Comment: Tried this. It copied the .resx and its containing folder to the /bin directory in IIS, is there a way to tell it not to do that?

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer with a (hopefully) more appropriate answer. I apologize for not reading your question carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much, jslatts, for your input!  I've upvoted it & marked it as answer!  Changing to "All files in this project" did get the resx files out of /bin folder, though it also carried extra files like all my web.config files over to IIS, I can live with that.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if there is any easy way to make it ignore extra web.config files short of manually editing the MSBuild scripts to do so. If you wanted to go down that path, it might take a bit of work but it certainly could be done.

Comment: You can exclude the extra .config files by unloading the project and editing the project file. In the PropertyGroup element, add elements like
  <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Web.Debug.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>